# RabbitTemplate extending DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I would like to use [RabbitTemplate#sendAndReceive](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html#sendAndReceive-java.lang.String-org.springframework.amqp.core.Message-) to send a message to a queue and receive multiple messages, not just one. I wanted to extend this behavior by using my own `MessageListenerContainer`, but `RabbitTemplate` seems to instantiate `DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer` [directly](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.java#L1701).

Currently, an exception is thrown when 2 messages with the same correlation-id arrive at `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to`:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1569) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1480) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1400) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1387) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1366) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.callExecuteListener(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:928) [spring-rabbit-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.handleDelivery(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:917) [spring-rabbit-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149) [amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104) [amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Reply received after timeout
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.onMessage(RabbitTemplate.java:2270) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer.lambda$setMessageListener$1(DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer.java:114) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1477) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Is there a different way (if any) to receive multiple responses when using `sendAndReceive` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not designed to do that; you would need to use a `RabbitTemplate.send()` operation and a stand-alone listener container and you would correlate the replies in your code.

**EDIT**

Here's one way to achieve it (as long as you know how many replies to expect)...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So53206036Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So53206036Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MultiReplyTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        MultiReplyTemplate template = new MultiReplyTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        template.setMessageConverter(listConverter());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public ListConverter listConverter() {
        return new ListConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter());
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public String listen1(String in) {
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "bar")
    public String listen2(String in) {
        return in + in;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MultiReplyTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            List<String> reply = template.convertSendAndReceiveAsType("fanout", "", "foo",
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() { });
            System.out.println(reply);
        };
    }

}

class MultiReplyTemplate extends RabbitTemplate {

    private static final byte[] NOBODY = new byte[0];

    private final Map<String, Message> replies = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // Not thread-safe but that's ok since the DRTMLC is single-threadded.
        String corr = message.getMessageProperties().getCorrelationId();
        Message combined = this.replies.get(corr);
        if (combined == null) {
            combined = new Message(NOBODY, new MessageProperties());
            combined.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().put("replies", new ArrayList<Message>());
            this.replies.put(corr, combined);
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Message> list = (List<Message>) combined.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().get("replies");
        list.add(message);
        if (list.size() == 2) {
            this.replies.remove(corr);
            combined.getMessageProperties().setCorrelationId(corr);
            super.onMessage(combined);
        }
    }

}

class ListConverter implements SmartMessageConverter {

    private final MessageConverter delegate;

    ListConverter(MessageConverter delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Message toMessage(Object object, MessageProperties messageProperties) throws MessageConversionException {
        return this.delegate.toMessage(object, messageProperties);
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromMessage(Message message) throws MessageConversionException {
        return this.delegate.fromMessage(message); // for listeners
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromMessage(Message message, Object conversionHint) throws MessageConversionException {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
        List<Message> list = (List<Message>) message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().get("replies");
        return list.stream()
                .map(m -> this.delegate.fromMessage(m))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

and

```
[FOO, foofoo]
```

Comment: I understand it was not intended for this, but it actually "almost works". Multiple reply messages are received, but since the listener does not expect multiple messages, it throws an exception as intended. I was just wondering if there was a way to customize `DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer` that the template creates so it can receive multiple messages. I was trying to avoid a standalone listener container and use the Direct Reply-to AMQP mechanism, even though it might be an abuse, it is what I need for the project. Thanks for the reply nonetheless!

Comment: It's not the container that doesn't support multiple replies, it's the template's `onMessage()` method. It's not clear to me how you will know when "all" replies are received, unless it's always a fixed number. You can subclass the template and override the `onMessage()` method; accumulate the replies then synthesize a single `Message` from the replies and call `super.onMessage()`.

Comment: I know in advance how many messages I intend to receive and would pass that as a parameter, i.e. `expectedReplies` and a `timeout`. That sounds like what I am trying to do, I'll try to implement using a subclassed `RabbitTemplate`, thanks!

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to create a dummy message and add the real replies to a header (`List<Message>`) then use a custom `MessageConverter` to create your actual reply for the sendAndReceive method.

Comment: Sorry, it seems there is a misunderstanding, the multi-message reply does not come from one application, there are multiple producers replying to the request message from different processes. Sort of like broadcast request-reply.

Comment: No; I meant in your subclass `onMessage()` method, assemble a single reply message from the various replies and then pass it to the `super.onMessage()` for conversion to your expected reply type.

Comment: It's an interesting use case; I edited the answer with how I might do it; note however, it doesn't have any logic to handle partial responses (missing replies).

Comment: Thank you, that is certainly a very good starting point! Appreciate all the help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183357/discussion-between-alturkovic-and-gary-russell).